# Chicago-biblatex fails to cite the bibliography (Overleaf)

Tags: bibliographies, citing, biblatex-chicago

My problem is this: I was using biblatex but was requested to use chicago-biblatex. Before I did so, all the references I had (in a .bib file) were cited correctly. After switching to chicago-biblatex, all I see in the citations are the citation keys, as if no .bib file is found. I'm using LuaLaTeX as the compiler (required for the emoji package). The document's first chapter (executive) has no citations in it. I'll leave it as is just in case.

Here's the code (sans identifying information):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{threats}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{emoji}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Table of Contents Formatting
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\vskip0pt}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\title{\Huge}


\author{Jo}  
\vspace{0.3in}

\date{December 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\underline{Workshop Participants / Contributors:} 

\underline{Acknowledgements:}


\newpage 
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{spacing}{0.95}
\tableofcontents
\end{spacing}


\newpage 
\include{introduction}


\newpage
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The \printbibliography command at the end raises the error that the bibliography is empty. However, I have hundreds of citations in my .bib file. Is there a clash I don't know about? Just not using any package at all, I get working citations. With biblatex-chicago, I get none.

Here's the relevant bibliography entry from the bib file:

```
@article{Bommasani2021,
   abstract = {Too long of an abstract.},
   author = {Rishi Bommasani et al},
   doi = {10.48550/arxiv.2108.07258},
   month = {8},
   title = {On the Opportunities and Risks of Foundation Models},
   url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.07258v3},
   year = {2021},
}
```

I should stress again that all the citation keys were working before trying to use chicago-biblatex. The file is called threats.bib. The error log has "output.bcf is malformed, last biblatex run probably failed. Deleted output.bbl"

When I delete all of the introduction file and just have:

```
 \section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}
    \subsection{Motivation}
    
    Something Something\autocite{Bommasani2021}.
```

the citations work. How should I proceed to figure out the issue now?

Update: I discovered that there are "%" signs in the bib file. I'll update again after removing all of them.

Update: That was the issue! Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should probably also provide sample bibtex data, and make your example self contained, we don't have access to the two files you include, please edit your example to not include external files.

Comment: Edited the include part that contains citations. I'll add the bibliography entry as you suggest.

Comment: Note that you are still loading stuff that others do not have access to and is the emoji package relevant for your document. It seems to need lualatex, a requirement not mentioned in your question.

Comment: I'm mentioned those too. Thanks!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the bib file is called `threats.bib`? What does the log say? I can make it compile just fine and the citation appears in the footnote.

Comment: Note that the `hyperref` package (with a few exceptions) needs to be the last package loaded.

Comment: Additionally you are still including a file we don't have access to. Works fine for me, when I'm very caseful as to what I name the `.bib` file.

Comment: can you edit your example check the problem still occurs if you remove `\include{executive}` if you need that file to show the problem, add it to the question

Comment: The file is called threats.bib. The error log has "output.bcf is malformed, last biblatex run probably failed. Deleted output.bbl" (I'll add this to the post too. Again, thanks.)

Comment: When I comment out the \include(executive), the compile fails. It says there's a runaway argument at line 52 ("\begin{document}")

I'm really at a loss right now.

Comment: The issue with the failed compile is solved by using hyperref last, thanks @daleif

Comment: The citations are still not working.

Comment: show your log you presumably have a error in `introduction.tex` (or `\end{document}` For `last biblatex run probably failed. Deleted output.bbl"` on overleaf use "clear cached files" button in the view logs

Comment: I discovered that there were "%" signs in the bib file. Removing them all fixed the issue. The citations now work. Thanks a lot for helping me stay sane! :)